# How can I get combobox ID to return to database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, combobox

```
void fill_cbcategoria()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string Query = "select * from Categoria";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                    string categoria = (string)dr.GetString(1);
                    cbcategoria.Items.Add(categoria);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am using this code to fill my category combobox:

```
private void btneditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string Query = "insert into dbPAP.Categoria (id_categoria, categoria)" + "values('" + this.cbcategoria.SelectedValue + this.cbcategoria.SelectedItem + "') ;";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Editado com sucesso!");
            while (dr.Read())
            {

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to update data to database, but is needed "`id_categoria`" but I don''t know how can I do it. In Table "`Categoria`" just got 2 parameters, that's "`id_categoria`" = 0 and "`categoria`" = 1. Problem is, can I get "`id_categoria`" value to update in database using `combobox.SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use executeNonQuery for executing insert command. `SqlDataReader` is usually used for read data from the database; you can try like the following:

```
   string Query = "insert into dbPAP.Categoria (id_categoria,categoria)values(@selectedVal,@selectedItem)";
   SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
   createCommand.Parameters.Add("@selectedVal", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.cbcategoria.SelectedValue;
   createCommand.Parameters.Add("@selectedItem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.cbcategoria.SelectedItem;
   createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();// return 1 in this case if insert success
```

few [suggestions](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-executereader-executenonquery.htm) for better understanding:

**ExecuteReader :** ExecuteReader used for getting the query results as a DataReader object. It is readonly forward only retrieval of records and it uses select command to read through the table from the first to the last.

**ExecuteNonQuery :** ExecuteNonQuery used for executing queries that does not return any data. It is used to execute the sql statements like update, insert, delete etc. ExecuteNonQuery executes the command and returns the number of rows affected.

You can read more about [The purpose of parameterized queries](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30147)